# Where to store the database of a python program?

Tags: python, linux, sqlite, pip, click

I am designing a small program to help me with the management of links for online classes.

It works in linux through the console, it is created as a python package, with setup.py to be able to install it by pip or pipx.

The data of classes, links, teachers, etc. is saved in a data.db file that works with sqlite3. I store it in the database folder, therefore the directory looks like this.
[workdir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgWrE.png)

db.py file finds database with these commands

```
dirname = os_path.dirname(__file__)
path = os_path.join(dirname, "database/")
```

**When I install it with pip --editable it works but without it it doesn't work.**

I understand why this happens and I think I could somehow force to include the database folder in site-packages / myproyect, but I think this solution is not professional at all and I don't like it.

So I come to you to ask for advice, **where do I store the database? In which directory?, How do I do it in the most professional way?**

P.S. it's my first project and I'd really appreciate your guiding me

project link: https://github.com/fraco-oxza/classgo

Comment: `__file__` is global set on every python module/script that returns the relative path to the *.py file that contains it.
So maybe you could try something like:
`mypath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Comment: thank you very much but i can get to the file location, the question is where should i save the database when pip installs the package?

Comment: i think it should be in the project dir, the same location of setup.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to use something like [*`platformdirs`*](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/), and store the database in "*user data dir*".